# How to improve the performance of loading a data from MS access into DataGridView?

Tags: .net, winforms

I have a Windows .Net code to read the query from MS Access 2010 database and show it in the DataGridView.

When I execute the query in MS Access it takes less than 7 seconds to show

When the same query is called from .Net using the below code it takes around 50 seconds and it loads 1200 rows with 21 columns. Even for sorting a columns(clicking on column header) takes more than 15 seconds

```
Using Con As New OleDbConnection(Connection String)
      Using da As New OleDbDataAdapter(strQuery, Con)
            Using datatable As New DataTable("data")
                 da.Fill(datatable)
                 datagrid.DataSource = datatable
            End Using
       End Using
End Using
```

Any way that i can improve the performance. Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: I assume WinForms.  Go to WPF ListView GridView with virtualization.

Comment: That shouldn't take that long for only 1200 rows.  What events are you using?  Post some of that code.  BTW, you shouldn't have `datatable` in a Using Bracket since you are actively using the data in the grid.

Comment: Improving performance is a very big question with many answers.  Can you list the things you've tried?  Do you have proper indexing / primary keys on your database, does the database exist on the same computer as the code, on a different computer on the network, somewhere on the internet, is it a parameterized query / stored procedure?

Also, you may want to consider refactoring the datasource assignment outside of your usings.

Comment: @LarsTech sorry i didnt get when you say datatable to be not there inside Using bracket

Comment: @xDaevax i think the query in the database is executing fast.. i told it executes in 7 seconds, wheere the time is taking only in binding.. no events nothing. its just a plain form with grid and button

Comment: @Blam i am very new to WPF, but think it is not difficult to migrate my existing code. Can you let me know what do you mean by "with virtualization"

Comment: @Sathish Look it up.  I mean what Microsoft means by virtualization.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the grid control and added again to the form and it worked great.
Not sure what had happened....